# How to escape single quotes in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my application I have a jsp page where the variables from server is assigned to the angular in client side. Please see the code below.

**jsp**

```
    <div ng-controller="HeaderController" 
         ng-init="init( {   firstName: '${customerInfo.firstName}',
                            lastName: '${customerInfo.lastName}' }) >
```

**Issue**

If the name contains a single quotes, 
     for example, if the firstName is `d'souza`, the code will be like this `firstName: 'd'souza'` which breaks. So how can this be escaped in JSP. Something like

```
{   firstName: 'escape(${customerInfo.firstName})',
                            lastName: '${customerInfo.lastName}' }
```

Comment: just json encode it

Comment: maybe help [escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652236/single-quote-is-not-supporting-in-angularjs-ng-click-if-multiple-paramet/47654872#47654872)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `escapeJavaScript` method of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` class. You have to include the common-lang library in your project, obviously.